# TableLayout & Scroll view stretching in layout

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout

I have a problem with a TableLayout that is showed with not aligned columns,
and also the view is getting streched that minifests by seeing the text on the buttons got cut.

**XML layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/libStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType = "fitXY"/>
</LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1"
        android:shrinkColumns="1">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/headerRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_col1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:text="@string/lib_dev_name" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_col2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape1"
                android:text="@string/lib_status" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/table_scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_devices"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1"
            android:shrinkColumns="1" >
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Col1" />
                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Col2" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@id/btnConnect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType = "fitXY"
        android:text="@string/lib_connect"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType = "fitXY"
        android:text="@string/lib_cancel"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**This how the layout appears when i run the application:**

[Screenshot of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siDrF.png)

Please your comments and advices.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerTable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >
    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/headerRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_col1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:text="@string/lib_dev_name" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_col2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape1"
            android:text="@string/lib_status" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/table_scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_devices"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Col1" />
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Col2" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>


<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal>

    <Button
       android:id="@id/btnConnect"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="@string/lib_connect"/>
    <Button
       android:id="@id/btnCancel"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="@string/lib_cancel"/>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: your code corrected the buttons stretching, thank you. But, the columns of the header are still not aligned withe the columns of in the tableLayout in scrollview.